# Cannot export jks file to p12, what's going on?

Tags: java, ssl, jks

I'm trying to export a private key and cert from a jks, Java Keystore, file to a PKCS12 file by running the following command:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore foo.jks -destkeystore foo.p12 -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Problem importing entry for alias foo: java.security.KeyStoreException: Key protection  algorithm not found: java.security.KeyStoreException: Certificate chain is not valid.
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: `key: command not found`

Comment: @nandsito what do you mean?

Comment: i was trying to bring to attention the bad-formatness of the question... actually i could successfully run that command